# Don't redirect on POST express.js

Tags: node.js, rest, express, post

I'm making a basic web app with Node.js and Express 4 and I'm trying to implement a "follow" function. I did some inspecting on the Github website and noticed it used a form with a follow button that would post to the server to follow a user. I think this sounds like a good approach but when I post I don't want to have to reload the page just like the github website.

How does one this inside of Express 4? Everything I put inside the .post route always end up in a page load. I'm pretty sure in jQuery's ajax method you can just return false and nothing will happen to the page, just the request will be sent which is what I want to happen because I'm using a RESTful api and I want to add the user to the current user's following but I don't want to have to use jQuery just for this function. I would prefer it be done in Express if possible, though any help would be appreciated.

---

**views/user.handlebars**

```
<h1>{{user.displayName}}</h1>
<p>@{{user.username}}</p>

<form action="" data-userid="{{user._id}}" method="post">
    <button name="follow" type="submit">Follow</button>
</form>
```

**routes/users.js**

```
app.route('/:username')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        // get :username user from api and load info
        ...
    })
    .post(function(req, res) {
        // don't reload page

        ???

        // send PUT :username user to current users following array
        ...
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're on the right track, but instead of putting your actions in the HTML (in your jade file) you're gonna have to add a `script` section to your jade and use javascript to attach an onClick event to the button so that when you press the button you invoke your ajax method.

Let me know if that doesn't make sense.